# NullPointerException while calling manager Method from execute quartz scheduler

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, quartz-scheduler

I've encorporated quartz scheduler in diffrent java file in my JSP Struts/Hibernate application. My execute method looks like below:

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext jExeCtx) throws JobExecutionException {
       try {
        userDetailManager = new UserDetailManagerImpl();
        userDetailManager.sendMailTxnDetailsEveryNight();
    } catch (ApplicationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JobClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
 }
```

Then im calling sendMailTxnDetailsEveryNight method and looks like:

```
public void sendMailTxnDetailsEveryNight() throws ApplicationException{
    List<RemittanceTransactionBean> rBean = remittanceTransactionDao.getTodayTxnSummary();
return rBean;
}
```

Im getting nullpointerException at given point :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mtmrs.business.user.impl.UserDetailManagerImpl.sendMailTxnDetailsEveryNight(UserDetailManagerImpl.java:754)
at com.mtmrs.util.common.JobClass.execute(JobClass.java:44)
```

How do i need to call the getTodayTxnSummary(); so that i dont get any error. I defined the remittanceTransactionDao in applicationContext as well:

```
<bean id="userDetailManager" parent="abstractTxDefinition">
    <property name="target">
        <bean class="com.mtmrs.business.user.impl.UserDetailManagerImpl">
        <property name="remittanceTransactionDao" ref="remittanceTransactionDao"></property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I tried debugging and see, the remittanceTransactionDao is null. I also tried setting below before calling method remittanceTransactionDao. This way the session variable im using in sendMailTxnDetailsEveryNight is null. I m stuck here.

```
remittanceTransactionDao = new RemittanceTransactionDaoHibernate(RemittanceTransaction.class);
```

Comment: The problem seems like in http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?32921-(DAO)HibernateDaoSupport-getSession-null-pointer-exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the classes and configured the follwing in my application-Context Dao.xml.

```
<bean name="runMeJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">

    <property name="jobClass" value="com.mtmrs.util.common.RunMeJob" />

    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="userDetailManager" value-ref="userDetailManager" />
        </map>
    </property>

</bean>
<bean id="cronTrigger"
      class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">

    <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 10,12,14,16,18,20,22,23 * * ?" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="runMeJob" />
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then i removed everything about the quartz implementaion code whatever i was trying to make, and  added this class:

```
package com.mtmrs.util.common;
import com.mtmrs.business.user.UserDetailManager;
import com.mtmrs.util.logger.MTMRSLogger;
import com.mtmrs.util.logger.ApplicationException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean;


public class RunMeJob extends QuartzJobBean {

UserDetailManager userDetailManager;

public UserDetailManager getUserDetailManager() {
    return userDetailManager;
}

public void setUserDetailManager(UserDetailManager userDetailManager) {
    this.userDetailManager = userDetailManager;
}

@Override
protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context)
        throws JobExecutionException {
    System.out.print("Entering Class: Job Class , method: execute");
    try {
        userDetailManager.sendMailTxnDetailsEveryNight();
    } catch (ApplicationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RunMeJob.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.print("Exiting Class: Job Class , method: execute");

}

}
```

Also i downgraded the version of quartz jar to 1.x. 
 I needed to use a method in userDetailManager (ie sendMailTxnDetailsEveryNight) object as the job that run every 2 hours as specified in the trigger.

Basically i followed this link: [Mykong](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example/) 
Hope this can be of help to someone.

Comment: This is the second time im using this :) The mkyong tutorial worked very well